# Creating an availability times for doctor in PostgreSQL using TSTZRANGE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make the doctor_availability like the below example, attribute which will be an array:

```
[
 [
  ["2020-03-10 09:00:00+00","2020-03-10 10:00:00+00"], False
 ],
...
...
]
```

This is how the doctor table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor
(
    doctor_id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    doctor_primary      BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    doctor_address      TEXT               NOT NULL,
    doctor_first_name   varchar(100)       NOT NULL,
    doctor_last_name    varchar(100)       NOT NULL,
    doctor_phone_number TEXT               NOT NULL,
    doctor_office       INT                NOT NULL REFERENCES office (office_id),
    doctor_spec         TEXT               NOT NULL,
    doctor_availability availability[],
    doctor_user         SERIAL             NOT NULL REFERENCES db_user (user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    doctor_diagnosis    INT,
    doctor_test         INT
);
```

The attribute doctor_availability is type availability, which is defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE availability AS
(
    available_time TSTZRANGE,
    taken          BOOLEAN
);
```

I have a trigger when a new doctor is doctor_availability into the new doctor:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_doctor_availability
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON doctor
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.doctor_availability IS NULL)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_availability();
```

The function insert_availability is defined as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_availability() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.doctor_availability := array(select tstzrange(a, a + '1 hour'::interval, '[]')
                                     from generate_series
                                              (
                                                  timestamp '2020-03-10 09:00:00',
                                                  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + '2 YEAR',
                                                  interval '1 HOUR'
                                              ) AS a (dt)
                                     WHERE MOD(EXTRACT(DOW FROM dt)::INTEGER, 6) != 0
                                       AND dt::TIME >= '09:00:00'
                                       AND dt::TIME < '17:00:00'::TIME);
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try to add a new doctor it throws an error:

Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO doctor(doctor_address, doctor_first_name, doctor_last_name, doctor_phone_number, doctor_office, doctor_spec,
                   doctor_user)
VALUES ('4444 Test St. Test, TX 90000', 'Test', 'Test_last', '992000000', 1, 'ENT', 1);
```

```
[22P02] ERROR: malformed record literal: "["2020-03-10 09:00:00+00","2020-03-10 10:00:00+00"]" Detail: Missing left parenthesis. Where: PL/pgSQL function insert_availability() line 3 at assignment
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? If yes, please post your solution :)